# Not getting the expected user information

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an admin page and allow only users with role 2 for some reason its not giving me the information I expected.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('includes/mysql_config.php');

    $id = isset($_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] : header('location: login.php');
    $user = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =".$_SESSION['id']) || false;

    if($user['role'] == '2'){
      echo "Hello $user['name']";
    }
    else {
      header('location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

When I do `vardump($user)` its giving me the output 1.

When I echo the `$_SESSION['id']` it is giving me the right id (the session id is the same as user id).

Comment: In the current code `var_dump($user)` returns whether a dump of `mysqli_result` object, or `false`, but not `1`.

Comment: You not fetching the results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now what you have done is, you just executed the query and had the resultset stored in `$user`. **You need to fetch the results from the Result Set**.

```
$user = mysqli_fetch_array($user);
```

Now it should work as expected.

---

**Update:** You should also handle the following:

- **Sanitization:** Make sure you use `'` for the values and `` ` `` for the column names. Also use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for escaping some obvious stuff.
- **Validation:** That's the next most important. Try checking if the resultset has any rows returned. You can do by using `mysqli_num_rows($user) > 0` or precisely in your case,  `mysqli_num_rows($user) == 1`.
- **Variables:** Here in the example, I have used the same `$user` for the Result Set as well as the row. It is always better to have two separate variables, say, `$userRes` (for result set) and `$userData` (for the fetched data).

Hope this should answer your question.

Comment: Thanks this one helped me out!

Comment: I will when the time limit is over.

Answer (score 0):

After a successful select query `mysqli_query()` will return an mysqli_result object. You have to itterate over that to get your results. For example:

```
$user = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =".$_SESSION['id']) || false;
if(user ){
     // Cycle through results
    while ($row = user ->fetch_object()){
        $users[] = $row;
    }
    $user->close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not fetching the results... If you check the manual, and look for the return value of [`mysqli_query()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), you'll find:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE

So go ahead and fetch it:

```
//$user = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =".$_SESSION['id']) || false; // I'm unfamiliar with this || false stuff.
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =".$_SESSION['id']);
$user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

It's also a good idea to sanitize your input (in order to prevent SQL-injection) and to check whether there are any results with `mysqli_num_rows()`.